# Interrupt Nested, Sequencing

Tags: linux-kernel, cpu, hardware, interrupt

I am reading the Linux Kernel documents and I have these questions(`X86_64` Arch);

1. When PIC sends an interrupt to CPU, will that disable that specific interrupt till the acknowledgement comes from CPU? If that is the case, why do we need to `local_irq_disable()` in the ISR?
2. Related to above question, but say if CPU is processing an interrupt in its ISR and if there are 3 interrupts send by the same device to CPU, how does this going to be handled? Will that be serialised in some buffer(if yes, where)?
3. `X86` architecture supports priority based interrupts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PIC is a very old interrupt controller, today interrupts are mostly delivered through MSI or through the APIC hierarchy.
The matter is actually more complicated with the IRQ routing, virtualization and so on.
I won't discuss these.

The *interrupt priority* concept still exists (though a bit simplified) and it works like this:
When an interrupt request is received by the interrupt controller, all the **lower** priority interrupts are masked and the interrupt is sent to the CPU.
What actually happens is that interrupts are ordered by their request number, with lower numbers having higher priority (0 has more priority than 1).
When *any* request line is toggled or asserted, the interrupt controller will scan the status of each request line from the number 0 up to the last one.
It stops as soon as it finds a line asserted or which is marked (with the use or a secondary register) in processing.
This way if request line 2 is first asserted and then request line 4 is, the interrupt controller won't server this last request until the first one is "done" because line 2 stops the scanning.

So `local_irq_disable` may be used to disable **all** interrupts, including those with **higher priority**.
AFAIK, this function should be rarely used today. It is a very simple, but inefficient, way to make sure no other code can run (potentially altering common structures).

In general, there needs to be some coordination between the ISR and the device to avoid losing interrupts.
Some devices require the software to write to a special register to let them know it is able to process the next interrupt. This way the device may implement an internal queue of notifications.
The keyboard controller works kind of like this, if you don't read the scancodes fast enough, you simply lose them.
If the device fires interrupts at will and too frequently, the interrupt controller can buffer the requests so they don't get lost.
Both the PIC and the LAPIC can buffer at most one request while another one is in progress (they basically use the fact that they have a request register and an in-progress register for each interrupt).
So in the case of three interrupts in a row, one is surely lost. If the interrupt controller couldn't deliver the first one to the CPU because a higher priority interrupt was in progress, then two will be lost.
In general, the software **doesn't** except the interrupt controller to buffer any request.
So you shouldn't find code that relies on this (after all, the only number in CS are 0, 1, and infinity. So 2 doesn't exist as far as the software is concerned).

The x86, as a CPU core, **doesn't** support priority when dealing with interrupt. If the interrupts are not masked, and a hardware interrupt arrives, it is served. It's up to the software and the interrupt controller to prioritize interrupts.
The PIC and LAPIC (and so the MSIs and the IOAPIC) both give interrupts a priority, so for all practical purposes the x86 supports a priority-based interrupt mechanism.

Note however that giving interrupt priority is not necessarily good, it's hard to tell if a network packet is more important than a keystroke.
So Linux has the [guideline to do as little work as possible in the ISR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44527695/linux-apic-interrupts-priority) and instead to queue the rest of the work to be processed asynchronously out of the ISR.
This may mean to just return from the ISR to work function in order to not block other interrupts.
In the vast majority of cases, only a small portion of code needs to be run in a critical section, a condition where no other interrupt should occur, so the general approach is to return the EOI to the interrupt controller and unmask the interrupt in the CPU as early as possible and write the code so that it can be interrupted.

In case one needs to stop the other interrupt for performance reasons, the approach usually taken is to split the interrupt across different cores so the load is within the required metrics.
Before multi-core systems were widespread, having too many interrupts would effectively slow down some operations.
I guess it would be possible to load a driver that would [denial other interrupts for its own performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20420645/how-to-give-highest-priority-to-ethernet-interrupt-in-linux) but that is a form of QoS/Real-time requirement that is up to the user to settle.